# Keyboard event not dispatching Enter key event in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, keyboard-events

I am using materialize-css's chips component in an angular app. To create chips I have to press enter. but in mobile, there is no enter key.

SO I have added textInput event on chips's input element, and if user press comma it will dispatch the enter key event.

```
__element.addEventListener('textInput', function (__event) {
      const keyCode = __event.data.charCodeAt(0);
      const COMMA_KEY_CODE = 44;
      if (keyCode == COMMA_KEY_CODE) {
        __event.preventDefault();
        __event.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: "Enter" }));
      }
});
```

On press of comma I am getting the event but it not dispatching the enter event.

But if I use the following line to dispatch enter key event

```
__event.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { keyCode: 13 }));
```

it shows

```
Argument of type '{ keyCode: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyboardEventInit'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'keyCode' does not exist in type 'KeyboardEventInit'.
```

But the same code works if i run it directly on the console.

Issue on GitHub : https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5722

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in Angular by binding a `keydown` event to your input with addition of `enter` key name to the event as

```
<input (keydown.enter)="onKeydown($event)">
```

And the definition for the event could be

```
onKeydown(event) {
    //This code will run only when an enter key is pressed
}
```

Comment: I want to hit enter automatically on press of comma